# Why can't I get the address of a type conversion in Go?

Tags: go

When I compile this code, the compiler tells me that I **cannot take the address of str(s)**.

```
func main() {
    s := "hello, world"
    type str string
    sp := &str(s)
}
```

So my question is whether a **type conversion** may look for a new address to locate the current new `s`, or something else that I haven't thought of?

Comment: A conversion result [is not addressable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Expressions)
>
> An expression specifies the computation of a value by applying
>   operators and functions to operands.
>
> [Conversions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)
>
> Conversions are expressions of the form T(x) where T is a type and x
>   is an expression that can be converted to type T.
>
> [Address operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators)
>
> For an operand x of type T, the address operation &x generates a
>   pointer of type *T to x. The operand must be addressable, that is,
>   either a variable, pointer indirection, or slice indexing operation;
>   or a field selector of an addressable struct operand; or an array
>   indexing operation of an addressable array. As an exception to the
>   addressability requirement, x may also be a (possibly parenthesized)
>   composite literal. If the evaluation of x would cause a run-time
>   panic, then the evaluation of &x does too.

Expressions are temporary, transient values. The expression value has no address. It may be stored in a register. A comversion is an expression. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    type str string
    s := "hello, world"
    fmt.Println(&s, s)

    // error: cannot take the address of str(s)
    sp := &str(s)
    fmt.Println(sp, *sp)
}
```

Output:

```
main.go:13:8: cannot take the address of str(s)
```

To be addressable a value must be persistent, like a variable. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    type str string
    s := "hello, world"
    fmt.Println(&s, s)

    ss := str(s)
    sp := &ss
    fmt.Println(sp, *sp)
}
```

Output:

```
0x1040c128 hello, world
0x1040c140 hello, world
```

Comment: If you want to convert the type but don't want to create a new variable you can just use this conversion:
`sp := (*str)(&s)`   
Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/3CqLeyebFha